# CUDA kernel with atomics producing wrong answer

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to understand the CUDA programming model and its features.As an exercise, I am trying to convert the following loop structure with a function call into an efficient CUDA kernel

```
//function call
bool gmul(int rowsize,int *Ai,int *Bj,int colsize)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < rowsize;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < colsize;j++)
        {
            if(Ai[i] == Bj[j])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Some for loop in main function is as follows

for(i = 0;i < q ;i++)
    {
        cbeg = Bjc[i];
        cend = Bjc[i+1];        
        for(j = 0;j < m;j++)
        {
            beg = Aptr[j];
            end = Aptr[j+1];            
            if(gmul(end - beg,Acol + beg,Bir + cbeg,cend - cbeg))
            {   
                temp++;             
            }                       
        }
        Cjc1[i+1] = temp ;              
    }
```

And my kernel with function call is as follows.

```
    __device__ bool mult(int colsize,int rowsize,int *Aj,int *Bi,int *val)
    {       
        for(int j = 0; j < rowsize;j++)
        {           
           for(int k = 0;k < colsize;k++)
            {   
              if(Aj[j] == Bi[k])
               {    
                return true;
                }                               
            }           
        }
            return false;       
    }


__global__ void kernel(int *Aptr,int *Aj,int *Bptr,int *Bi,int rows,int cols,int *count,int *Cjc)
    {
        int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        int i;
        if(tid < cols)
        {
            int beg = Bptr[tid];
            int end = Bptr[tid+1];
            for(i = 0;i < rows;i++)
            {
                int cbeg = Aptr[i];
                int cend = Aptr[i+1];
                if(mult(end - beg,cend - cbeg,Aj+cbeg,Bi+beg,count))
                {
                    //atomicAdd(count,1);
                                    //Changes made are in next line
                              atomicAdd(Cjc+tid+1,1);           
                }
            }
            //atomicAdd(Cjc+tid+1,*count);              
        }               
    }
```

What I want is that whenever `__device__ mult` is returned with `true` value, my global kernel function should increment the counter for that particular thread and once the for loop (in kernel function) ends,it should store the value into `Cjc` array and count is handed over to other threads for increment operation. However, I am not getting the expected value. All I get in this `Cjc` array is the final count once all the threads have finished executing.

I am using GTX 480 with CC 2.0

Any suggestions/hints as to why am I getting wrong answers or optimizations for this CUDA kernel will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
*****************Solved**********************

Right now,I am facing an issue that whenever I reach the size of 4000 and beyond, I am getting the value of all elements in an array as `0`. Here is how I launch the kernel.

```
    int numBlocks,numThreads;

        if(q % 32 == 0)
        {
            numBlocks = q/32;
            numThreads = 32;
        }
        else
        {
            numBlocks = (q+31)/32;
            numThreads = 32;
        }
findkernel<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(devAptr,devAcol,devBjc,devBir,m,q,d_Cjc);
```

I was wondering I am crossing any limits for block or grid dimensions but for CC 2.0, I think I am just right to launch the sufficient blocks and threads that dont cross any limits. I wonder why still all the answers are coming out as `0`.

Comment: Your first step should be to google for "parallel prefix sum" or "scan". That will bring up some sound algorithmic bases for implementing this sort of cumulative summation. There are already a number of good CUDA implementations available you could look at to learn how implement it correctly.

Comment: @talonmies..Thanks...I will try to store the individual counts in an array and then I will try to implement parallel prefix sum or scan...I wonder if thrust has any implementation of the same...

Comment: `thrust::exclusive_scan` or `thrust::inclusive_scan` are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @talonmies...I made the changes and used thrust::inclusive_scan as you suggested. Everything is working fine until I reach the size of 4000 and beyond.I am getting array with all the values as `0`. I have updated the question with my kernel launch parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written parallel threads that read and write `count` without synchronization.  The threads run concurrently in an unpredictable order, so threads atomically modify `count` and read `count` in an unpredictable order.  The expression `*count` will produce different results depending on the exact execution order.

> once the for loop (in kernel function) ends, it should store the value into `Cjc` array and count is handed over to other threads for increment operation.

There is no synchronization, so no thread waits for another thread to finish the loop.  Instead of making all threads share the same storage for `count`, why not give each thread a different piece of storage?  Then the threads will not influence one another's result.  You can run a scan kernel after this one to combine results.

Comment: @Heatsink....Thanks...I will try to put results of each count in an array and then I will try to apply parallel prefix sum or scan over it.